# Codeception auto start and auto shutdown selenium server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm using Codeception and I want to do Selenium tests.

Obviously, I need Selenium server running and I can spin it up with:

```
java -jar ./path/to/selenium/binary
```

However, I've used another testing framework in past which allowed me to specify this path in config file. Then, whenever I did something like `codecept run`, the framework automatically started selenium server and also shutted it down after all tests were completed.

Can I do this with Codeception? I tried to put `exec()` in _bootstrap file but it didn't work..

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to do this?  I'm need the same thing so I can run a suite of tests using Selenium then shut it down and run another suite of tests using PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using phantomjs - headless alternative to selenium. [This extension](https://github.com/site5/phantoman) starts phantomjs automatically with `codecept run`. Also phantomjs is faster than selenium.

You can write your own [extension](http://codeception.com/docs/08-Customization#Extension) for running selenium - have a look at [this file](https://github.com/site5/phantoman/blob/master/src/Phantoman.php).

Comment: PhantomJS is not maintained anymore: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE/5Z3SMZrqAQAJ

Answer (score 0):

I start my tests with a bash script and then start and stop selenium via screen:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Start selenium in detached screen
screen -d -m -S "selenium" java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./path/to/chromedriver  -jar ./path/to/selenium/binary || true

./vendor/bin/codecept run -c codeception.yml --fail-fast --coverage --steps --coverage-html --html || error=true

# quit selenium
screen -S selenium -X quit || true
```

This might not fit the use-case but I can execute my code in my bash on Windows and Ubuntu as well as via my jenkins build process.